# Angularjs ng-model with number input

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to retrieve an input[number] in my controller.

I found a solution which said to add a $scope.$watch on the input.

I tried it but now my number is "NaN".

```
<div class="offerText">
    <label class="form-inline" ng-if="!admin">What will it cost ? <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="estimation"/></label>      
    <label class="form-inline">Comments <textarea rows="3" cols="50" class="form-control" ng-model="comments"></textarea></label>
</div>
```

And In my controller

```
    $scope.$watch('estimation', function (val, old) {
        $scope.estimation = parseFloat(val);
    });
```

Thx for your help !

Comment: when value is `""` or `null` conversion will obiviously parseFloat would be always `NaN`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a watch. The problem here is that the input is inside an ng-if directive, which defines its own scope. The estimation is stored in the `ng-if` scope instead of being stored in the controller scope.

Rule or thumb: always have a dot in your ng-model.

In your controller, add

```
$scope.data = {};
```

And in the html, use

```
ng-model="data.estimation"
```

and

```
ng-model="data.comments"
```

Answer (score 0):

Test if the new value is not undefined or null or something falsy, this happens because angular loops a few times through the watchs and the models, this process is call dirty checking

```
$scope.$watch('estimation', function (val, old) {
        if (!val) {
          return;
        }
        $scope.estimation = parseFloat(val);
    });
```

Comment: console.log("ESIMATION : " + $scope.estimation);

It says "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

When your value is `""` or `null` you will always get parseFloat result as `NaN`

```
$scope.$watch('estimation', function (val, old) {
    return !isNaN(val) ? parseFloat(val): 0; //considering default value is 0 
});
```

Other possible way would get value on change, using `ng-change` directive.

```
<div class="offerText">
    <label class="form-inline" ng-if="!admin">What will it cost ? <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="estimation" ng-change="changedEstimation(estimation)"/></label>      
    <label class="form-inline">Comments <textarea rows="3" cols="50" class="form-control" ng-model="comments"></textarea></label>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.changedEstimation =  function(val){
   return !isNaN(val) ? parseFloat(val): 0;
}
```

Comment: console.log("ESIMATION : " + $scope.estimation); 
It says : "Undefined"

Comment: on initial it will be `undefined`, after changing value you can get the changed val..